# Помогите разобраться со списками Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот есть такое поле в bitrix24 никак не могу к нему обратиться.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно извлечь значения из div элемента то можно воспользоваться  jq скриптом по типу
JSON.parse($('.selector').attr('data-type'))
Значения соответственно изменяете под себя